# how to disable ion-item in ionic with angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have many `ion-items` on my screen. I want to disable them every times i click a `+` icon my screen which blurs the screen and I want to disable all the clicks at that time how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

For you to blur the screen when you click a button, you can just use a empty div which can cover the height and width of the screen, and using ng-if you can toggle the div programmatically.

In html :

```
<div class="mr-blur" ng-if="toggle"></div>
```

In CSS :

```
.mr-blur{
height : 100vh;//full viewport height
width : 100vw;//full viewport width
background-color : white;//color of the overlay
opacity : 0.6;//to show a little bit of the iactive screen
z-index : 9999!important; //To put it on top of all elements
}
```

In JS :

```
$scope.plusButton = function(){ //function to be called when plus button is clicked 
    $scope.toggle = !$scope.toggle;//
}
```